# SYS_B_x in Oracle query result column name

Tags: oracle

I've faced with some weird behaviour of Oracle 11 DB.

I have a simple query selecting data from a view:

```
select 
    (case when exists(select 1 from MY_VIEW v where v.func_name = 'NAME') then 1 else 0 end) 
from dual
```

`MY_VIEW` looks like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW MY_VIEW 
AS
    SELECT a.object_name AS func_name, NULL AS func_desc
    FROM USER_ARGUMENTS a
```

In the result set, I receive result with columnName: `(CASEWHENEXISTS(SELECT:"SYS_B_0"FROMMY_VIEWVWHEREV.FUNC_VALUE=:"SYS_B_1")THEN:"SYS_B_2"ELSE:"SYS_B_3"END)`

And when I'm trying to execute this query by Hibernate, it falls with error

> SQL Error: 17133 "Invalid identifier or literal"

while extracting column alias.

Error causes when I'm using ojdbc8 driver, with ojdbc6 driver all is OK.

Strange thing is that I have problems only when I'm querying from this particular view.

When I made same query from another View, created from simple table, everything was ok.

Furthermore, I have another Oracle 11 DB and there result set column name for this query looks common:

```
(CASEWHENEXISTS(SELECT1FROMMY_VIEWVWHEREV.FUNC_VALUE='NAME')THEN1ELSE0END)
```

My question is: why and when Oracle replaces values in query string on **:"SYS_B_x"** ?

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all, you need to add an alias for that column.
2. You get :SYS_B_x because of the parameter cursor_sharing=force on that database.

Comment: `you need to add an alias for that column` Yes, I've solve this problem just like that ) Thanks!